# Minimize function with respect to constraint

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

Consider the function $ f(a) =\sum_{k=1}^N \|a- x_k\|^2$, where $a, x_k \in \mathbb{R}^d$, which we want to minimize w.r.t. $\|a- c\|^2=1$

Building the lagrangian yields: $\sum_{k=1}^N \|a- x_k\|^2 + \lambda (1-\|a- c\|^2) $
Taking derivative w.r.t. $a$ yields: $$ N a - \sum_{k=1}^N x_k - \lambda (a- c) =0   $$
U
Dividing by $N$ yields: $$ (a - m) - \lambda' (a-c)=0 $$, where $m:= 1/N\sum_{k=1}^N x_k$ and $\lambda' = \lambda/N$
Using hint in comments:
$$a  (1-  \lambda') +\lambda'c - m=0  $$
$$ a = \frac{m-\lambda'c}{1-\lambda'} (*)$$
Using the constraint, we get:

$$\|\frac{m-c}{1- \lambda'}\|^2 =1 \Rightarrow 1 - \pm \| m-c\| = \lambda'$$

Putting that in (*) yields: $\frac{m - (1 - \pm \| m-c\|)c }{\mp \| m-c\|}$

How do I find the solution then?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134748/discussion-on-question-by-sarah-minimize-function-with-respect-to-constraint).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this problem is to write
$$ \mathbf{a}=\mathbf{c}+\frac{1}{\| \mathbf{u} \|} \mathbf{u}$$
The objective function now reads
$$ \phi(\mathbf{u})
= \sum_n \| \mathbf{b}_n + \frac{1}{\| \mathbf{u} \|} \mathbf{u}  \|^2
$$
where $\mathbf{b}_n=\mathbf{c}-\mathbf{x}_n$.

The gradient is (for one element)
$$
\frac{2}{\| \mathbf{u} \|} 
\left[
\mathbf{b}_n 
- \frac{\mathbf{b}_n^T \mathbf{u}}{\| \mathbf{u} \|^2}  \mathbf{u}
\right]
$$

Finally the solution is a multiple of
$\sum_n \mathbf{b}_n 
= N (\mathbf{c} - \bar{\mathbf{x}} )$
and thus
$$ \mathbf{a}=\mathbf{c}+\frac{1}{\| \mathbf{c} - \bar{\mathbf{x}} \|} 
(\mathbf{c} - \bar{\mathbf{x}} )$$